# "Copy Local" for website references

Tags: .net, visual-studio

VS2005.NET

I have a website project that references 3rd party dll's and i'd like to have the DLL copied to the bin folder similar to the way Copy Local works for "regular" .Net Project

I'm not sure how to get the referenced file to the output folder for inclusion in the deployment besides dropping it into the project itself(ugly and sloppy, imo).

Is there something like copy local for Web projects?

EDIT: i'm open to suggestions as to what a better solution is than what i'm trying.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding a reference to the DLL in your project?  Doing that SHOULD add it to the bin directory in your project and include it in your deployments.

Comment: AH! it does. But only if the DLL is not already GAC'd.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Add the reference and just set "Copy Local" attribute to "true" from the property windows of assembly.

Comment: Maybe i'm just an idiot, but on my website solutions there's no References folder like on "Standard" projects.

Comment: OP is referring to website project and those don't track references in their .*proj files, because they don't have project files.